# IText html to pdf img

Tags: html, pdf-generation, itext

I am converting a html document to a pdf document and send it with java mail.
I want to insert an image on the top of the pdf document with:

```
<img alt="Logo" class="logo" src="https://www.somesite.org/images/logo.png"/>
```

But it isnt shown in the pdf document.
The link is working correctly, i tried it in my browser.

When i put in a absolute path to the image on my server he finds the path, but the email programm doesnt have access to our server of course, except of the link i want to use...

Isnt it possible to use such links?

EDIT:

```
final DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        documentBuilderFactory.setValidating(false);
        DocumentBuilder builder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        builder.setEntityResolver(FSEntityResolver.instance());
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

    String filename = wrapper.GetHtmlFilename(this.getClass().getName());
    String html = wrapper.GetHtmlFile(filename, "UTF-8");
    String result = wrapper.GetBody(html);

    document = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(result.getBytes("UTF-8")), "UTF-8");

    baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    renderer = new ITextRenderer();

    renderer.setDocument(document, null);
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(baos);
```

Comment: Part of your question is missing. Should there be code between "I want to insert an image on the top of the pdf document with:" and "But it isnt shown..."? I don't see any.

Comment: Also how do you convert HTML to PDF? Surely you're not using the deprecated HTMLWorker class, are you? If so, please switch to using XML Worker.

Comment: I am using IText, wait i edit it in the mainpost

Comment: I'm the original author of iText, and I can assure you the 'ITextRenderer' is NOT an official class. You are using Flying Saucer which is a product built on top of iText. Your problem is related to Flying Saucer, isn't it? It's not a real iText problem.

Comment: Ok i tried to switch to XMLWorker, i downloaded the newest itext-5.3.2 .zip and xmlworker-1.1.6.zip, but HTMLParsingDefault cant be found. Where is this class located? Can you help me please?

Comment: Could you help me please, with the HTMLParsingDefault Class? I dont know where to find it in the official jar's

Comment: The examples have moved: http://sourceforge.net/p/itext/code/5423/tree/tutorial/templates/src/main/java/tutorial/xmlworker/ and they are outdated. The documentation will be rewritten after the white paper on digital signatures is finished.